# Vue Js Nginx Docker connect to Backend

Tags: spring-boot, docker, vue.js, nginx, kubernetes

I've developed vue js front end and I could communicate backend using axios call and when I call I need to specify backend service port and endpoint. how can I use nginx and docker and then after I use nginx and docker how app communicate with backend ? ultimately I need to deploy front end and backend services on kubernetes cluster.

I've read many tutorial about this and I don't have clear idea in concept and also need to implement the solution. I have never use nginx before

Backend : `http://localhost:8084`

Here is my axios call

```
import axios from 'axios'



const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8084'



    class NotificationDataService {
    
        
        retrieveAllNotifications() {
            
            return axios.get(`${API_URL}/notification/getall`);
        }
    
    
    
    
    }
    
    export default new NotificationDataService()
```

Answer (score 1):

with Docker (and thus Kubernetes) approach you have to separate the container from your Frontend and the container from your Backend.

In Kubernetes you can use an Ingress. It is a reverse proxy, so you don't need Nginx. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

To configure the URL of your Backend in your Vue.js application, I advise you not to use a constant variable as you do, but the configuration system of the Framework: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes.

You need to expose your frontend and backend with your Ingress, because your Axios calls are sent from the client to the backend. So you could have :

- [www.mydomain.com/](http://www.mydomain.com/) for your Frontend
- [www.mydomain.com/api](http://www.mydomain.com/api) for your backend

And now your frontend has only made calls to `www.mydomain.com/api`.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)